# Trouble with Redis LATENCY RESET Command Not Resetting Metrics in Sidecar Container

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

I'm currently in the process of developing a Redis sidecar container to collect latency and other metrics from Redis. To retrieve latency metrics, I'm utilizing the LATENCY HISTOGRAM command. Since I'm polling at fixed intervals to gather these metrics, I expected to use the LATENCY RESET command to reset the latency metrics during each polling interval. However, it seems that the command is not resetting the latency metrics as intended. I have confirmed that the configuration setting CONFIG SET latency-tracking yes is set to true.

Here's an illustrative example of the issue:
[part_1_of_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9lff.png)
[part_2_of_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq4lA.png)

I am using Redis version 7.2.3, as indicated by the output of `Redis> INFO`. I have also attempted to check `Redis> INFO LATENCY`, which did not reset after executing `Redis> INFO LATENCY`. The command `Redis> LATENCY RESET` is also not providing any results.

```
`[Redis> INFO ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlNIh.png)` 
`[Redis> INFO LATENCY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2tsR.png)`
`[Redis> LATENCY RESET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkPPN.png)`
```